# Find minimum distance between 2 points in 2 arrays

Tags: c#, algorithm, distance, min, points

I have 2 lists containing points (x,y and z) and would like to find the closest points.

I assume I need to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myarray1.Count; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < myarray2.Count; j++)
  {
    // Calculate the quadratic distance between 2 points (point in index i and j)
    // Then store the minimum distance I guess?   
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? Converting the high-level idea to actual code? Are you having trouble with any specific part? Do you have some actual code that isn't working which we can help you with?

Comment: if you care about efficiency, kd trees are your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the distance:

```
double sqr(double x) {return x*x;}

double distance(MyPoint a, MyPoint b) {
  return sqrt(sqr(a.x-b.x)+sqr(a.y-b.y)+sqr(a.z-b.z);
}
```

Then in the second loop you store the minimum distance found so far:

```
double d = distance(myarray1[i],myarray2[j]);
if (d<min_d) min_d = d;
```

where min_d is defined at the beginning:

```
double min_d = Float.MAX_VALUE;
```

Comment: Your method doesn't work if the base of `pow` is negative, so you should say `pow(fabs(...), 2)` or `Math.Pow(Math.Abs(...), 2)`. Better yet, skip the `pow` function and implement squaring `x` as `x*x`. (Also, if you are just _comparing_ distances to find the shortest, it is enough to compare squaresm, which eliminates `sqrt`, but admittedly, that's nitpicking.)

Comment: @MOehm Are you certain doesn't `pow(a.x-b.x,2)` work when the base is `a.x-b.x` is negative and exponent is a positive whole number?

Comment: @chux: I was certain, because I have this notion of `pow(a, b) == exp(log(a) * b)`, but it turns out I was wrong. I had looked at this MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but missed the part about the non-integer exponent. I don't use C# and have a C background, but it turns out that C's `pow` can handle negative bases with integer exponents, too. Still, I prefer plain multiplication for squares and bet it's faster, if only marginally.

Comment: I find very disappointing that the Math library of Java does not have an sqr function... How can it be like that?

Answer (score 4):

another option is to use [Kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree)
using the [Nearest neighbour search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree#Nearest_neighbour_search) will give you a `O(log n)` complexity to find the nearest point to a given set of points, and your code will have `O( n log n)`, instead of `O (n^2)`.

see [here](http://blog.noldorin.com/2011/03/kd-trees-for-dotnet/) for implementation and example of how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
  double min_dist = DOUBLE_MAX;
  for (i = 0; i < myarray1.Count; i++)
   {
     for (j = 0; j < myarray2.Count; j++)
     {
       curr_dist = dist(a[i],a[j]);  
       if( min_dist > curr_dist)
         {
              min_dist = curr_dist;
         }
     }
   }
```

where

```
double dist(Point a, Point b) {
  return sqrt(pow(a.x-b.x,2)+pow(a.y-b.y,2)+pow(a.z-b.z,2);
}
```

Comment: Whats the perfomance of this last one with myarray2 being 900,000 elements and myarray1 250 as an example? Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

In C# I would do this using Linq.

First I would define the function that calculates the distance between two points as in Emanuelle Paolini's answer:

```
public double Distance(Point p1, Point p2)
{
   return Math.Sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p1.y) * (p1.y - p1.y) + (p1.z - p1.z) * (p1.z - p1.z));
}
```

Then I would query the two lists as follows:

```
var distanceQuery = from p1 in myarray1
                    from p2 in myarray2
                    select Dist(p1, p2);
```

And finally I would retrieve the minimum distance:

```
var minimumDistance = distanceQuery.Min();
```

Comment: is Linq faster than doing 2 for loops?

Comment: Actually, Linq is probably much slower here according to a quick test I ran.

Answer (score 0):

Formula is

> `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(x1-x2),2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(y1-y2),2)+ Math.pow(Math.abs(z1-z2),2))`